# Boot freezing after sda3_crypt password

Tags: ubuntu, desktop-environment, lxde

I am new to linux. I was getting some trouble with excessive ram usage on ubuntu 18.04, and after searching around i found out about desktop environments.

I then installed LXDE and logged into it, but i wasn't able to find a program called sublime text. I decided to log into the openbox desktop environment, that appeared on the list after i installed LXDE. after logging the only thing that appeared was the cursor and a purple background. I turned the computer off after a while. When i turned it on again it got stuck loading after putting the sda3_crypt password.

It was set to login automatically to a non-root account. When this auto login happens, it logs with the last desktop environment used before turning off. So i suspect it has something to do with openbox

Comment: Probably the system started checking the filesystems. If you have a splash screen during boot, press the `ESC` key to see what is going on.

Comment: It did start checking the filesystems. There was a message saying to press ctrl+c to stop. I did and it booted, but didn't do the auto login. I didn't try to log with openbox again, i'm still not sure if it is the culprit

Comment: Filesystem checks occur regularly after a certain time or a certain amounts of reboots. You should really wait until the check ends.